# Defining beans per multiple spring profiles

Tags: java, spring, profiles

I have 3 profiles in my app called: dev, test, prod. 
I want to use spring profiles to customize bean injection so that for profile dev and test I will have one bean implementation and for profile prod I will have another. 
The question is how to achieve that. How I can setup one bean to be active within two different profiles.
I tried something like this:

```
@Component
@Profile("dev, test")
class DevTestBean{}
```

but unfortunatelly spring sees it as a single profile called dev comma space test.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to change to `@Profile({"dev", "test"})`

The value must be declared as Set.
See the [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html)

> If a @Configuration class is marked with @Profile, all of the @Bean
>   methods and @Import annotations associated with that class will be
>   bypassed unless one or more of the specified profiles are active. This
>   is analogous to the behavior in Spring XML: if the profile attribute
>   of the beans element is supplied e.g., , the
>   beans element will not be parsed unless at least profile 'p1' or 'p2'
>   has been activated. Likewise, if a @Component or @Configuration class
>   is marked with @Profile({"p1", "p2"}), that class will not be
>   registered or processed unless at least profile 'p1' or 'p2' has been
>   activated.

Answer (score 3):

XML solution has not been placed in official documentation:

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.12.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-definition-profiles

so for the record I will put it here:

```
<beans profile="dev,foo,bar">
  <!-- (...) -->
</beans>
```